# Refresh Test Database from Production

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is the best way to refresh the data in the test database from production?
I have seen similar questions here and all of them suggest to take the full export of production db, delete test db and then import the production dump.

Is there any way by which I can just export the newly added data in production and put it in test db ?

Comment: Please give more information about what kind of database you are using.

Comment: Unless you want to spend a lot of money for solutions like [Delphix](https://www.delphix.com) there is no way around the export/import or a `rman` backup/restore (it is a bit easier in Oracle 12.2 where you can take a snapshot of a PDB without taking the the instance down)

Comment: @JacobPålsson I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: another (expensive) option is to keep the data in synch between prod and test using goldengate

Comment: @sandman I can't use any tool (expensive or free). If no option is available i have to go with full export.

Comment: You can investigate flashback_scn parameter of expdp (data pump) if you want to take partial (current) exports of your prod database

Answer (score 0):

Besides full database export / import, I think you are looking at Test Data Management tools like IBM Infosphere Optim that manages the test data life cycle. Optim and other tools offer the functions that you are looking for.